# Bootstrap - Show a PHP file and switch active class

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do is a Navbar is stored in a file called index.php. This is the main page which shows up. When the user clicks a tab in the Navbar, in the body part, another php shows up and the tab becomes active. When the user clicks an other tab, the "active" should Switch Places. I'm having trouble with showing the php and switching the active class. Any Help?

What I was able to do:

There's a `script` above the navbar code which describes the path of the `.php` file and tells to show it where it is bounded with.

The code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function homeshow() {
    $.get("index.php");
    return false;
}
function aboutshow() {
    $.get("about.php");
    return false;
}
</script>
```

One of Navbar's link or Navigation Button should enable the Javascript/jQuery code to show up between `<p></p>` tags located in the body. I've tried this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="active"><a href="#" class onclick="homeshow();">Home</li>
      <li><a href="#" class onclick="aboutshow();">About</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you mean by "switch"?

Comment: I have a Navbar, I go to another page, the navbar should switch the position of being _Active_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to check the active tab in a standard click event then the `active` class wont have been added to the most recently selected tab until after the event.

Subscribe to the bootstrap `show.bs.tab` instead.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```

See [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) for more info.

Comment: Some of your answer is correct, but I have a new problem which is now in the Question.

Comment: @ShahrozAsif This answer was correct for your initial question. If you have a new question then you should create a new question not modify an old one. Best practice is to leave this question as answered to help others with the same issue Questions should be edited to add more information to help users answer your question not change the context of the question entirely.

Comment: I am unable to ask/post new questions as new questions are no longer accepted from my account. All I can do is to improve old questions to recover negative votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery or javascript code to change the active state from the previous li to the one you clicked on.

Example with jQuery:

```
$('ul.navbar-nav a').on('click', function () {
  $('ul.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: In a <script>your code...</script> tag in the template/page where you have this Navbar code.

Comment: If I want to store this piece of code in main.js and link it with multiple webpages, will it work? Example: I have index.html with active navbar li. Once the user visits the new page (about.html) will it automatically switch places?